# Setup username/email and permissions in a Git repository

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-config

I have two Github accounts: one used from work created under user email: `rperez@email1.com` and the second one used for personal projects under user email: `reynierpm@email2.com`

I have setup `rperez@email1.com` to be the global by running the following commands:

```
git config --global user.name "rperez"
git config --global user.email "rperez@email1.com
```

I need to work in one of the personal projects from work so I have cloned the repository and now I am trying to setup the second username to be the one making the commits to this personal repository so I have run the following commands:

```
git config user.name "reynierpm"
git config user.email "reynierpm@email2.com
```

For some reason as soon as I try to push something to the repo I got this error:

```
Push failed 
Failed with error: ERROR: Permission to reypm/php55-dev.git denied to rperez. 
Could not read from remote repository.
```

Why is trying to push changes as `rperez` and not as `reynierpm`?

Below is the output of the command `git config -l` in case someone need it:

```
$ git config -l
user.name=rperez
user.email=rperez@email1.com
gc.autodetach=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:reypm/php55-dev.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
user.email=reynierpm@email2.com
user.name=reynierpm
```

What's wrong on this setup?

Note: `@email1.com` and `@email2.com` are fake domain, is just used for not show the real address.

**UPDATE #1**

After follow the suggestions from comments this is what I have in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
#rperez account
Host github.com-rperez
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

#reypm account
Host github.com-reypm
    HostName github.com
    User git  
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_reynierpm
```

This is the output of `ls -la ~/.ssh`:

```
$ ls -la ~/.ssh/
total 32
drwx------.  2 rperez rperez 4096 Sep 27 10:21 .
drwx------. 29 rperez rperez 4096 Sep 27 09:54 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 rperez rperez  304 Sep 27 10:30 config
-rw-------.  1 rperez rperez 3243 Sep 21 09:35 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--.  1 rperez rperez  749 Sep 21 09:35 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------.  1 rperez rperez 1675 Sep 27 09:33 id_rsa_reynierpm
-rw-r--r--.  1 rperez rperez  401 Sep 27 09:33 id_rsa_reynierpm.pub
-rw-r--r--.  1 rperez rperez 2039 Sep 26 10:19 known_hosts
```

And finally the output of `git config -l`:

```
$ git config -l
user.name=rperez
user.email=rperez@email1.com
gc.autodetach=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:reypm/php55-dev.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
user.email=reynierpm@email2.com
user.name=Reynier Perez
remote.reypm.url=git@github.com:php55-dev.git
remote.reypm.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/reypm/*
```

Pushing changes into the repository `php55-dev` turn into this error:

```
Bad owner or permissions on /home/rperez/.ssh/config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Something still wrong in this setup, what's it?

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to push via HTTPS? If so, did you try to do the following? `git push https://<username>@github.com/<github repository> <local branch name>:<remote branch name>`

Comment: @Fadi, that's not the case, I am pushing through SSH for sure

Comment: Ah, my bad I didn't see the `remote.origin.url` when I commented.. my bad!!! Check this out: https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

Comment: Let me know if that works! :D

Comment: @Fadi yup, giving this a try, just one doubt: let's said that `rperez` is authorized to `repo1` and `reynierpm` is authorized to `repo2` what would be the right URL on the `Host` definition? I mean where in the ex says: `Host github.com-activehacker`

Comment: So the Host would be something like `github.com-rperez` for `repo1` and `github.com-reynierpm` for `repo2`.. And then you just use `github.com-rperez` and `github.com-reynierpm` instead of the hostname in your URL:

Comment: `git remote add rperez git@github.com-rperez:whatever.git`

Comment: `git remote add reynierpm git@github.com-reynierpm:whatever.git`

Comment: Also, one thing you need to add under the `IdentityFile` is this: `IdentitiesOnly yes` to prevent the use of default IDs..

Comment: @Fadi check **UPDATE #1** on the OP, still not working